# Hover starts animation and stop hover will make it go backwords

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I was wondering if there is any way to make an icon "open" and then "close".
is there any way hover over an animation to make it start and then, when you stop hovering over it, play a different animation that is identical to the original but in reverse and start from the point in which the first animation was left at.
For example:
You hover over an image for 3s and it will play an 5s animation that won't stop until you stop hovering over it. Once you stop hovering over the animation, it won't finish playing it, but it will play the reverse animation starting on 2s and ending in 5s.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the transition property for this. For example. Run the following snippet and hover over the square and then hover out to check if this is what your looking for.

```css
.square {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  background: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.square:hover{
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

**[Update based on first comment]**

I have developed a both jquery and pure css solution like this some time back. It included an envelop that opened up to reveal its text content. Below is the pure css snippet. Hope this helps you and anyone else who is looking for this.

```css
body{
            margin: 0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        #envelope-bg {
            position: relative;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        .envelope-container {
            position: relative;
            height: 405px;
            width: 405px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            border-radius: 2px;
            -ms-border-radius: 2px;
            -moz-border-radius: 2px;
            -o-border-radius: 2px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        }

            .envelope-container .envelope {
                position: absolute;
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -100px;
                top: 50%;
                margin-top: -100px;
                background: #F9F9F9;
                transform: rotate(-180deg);
                transition: 2s ease all;
                -ms-transition: 2s ease all;
                -moz-transition: 2s ease all;
                -o-transition: 2s ease all;
                -webkit-transition: 2s ease all;
                -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            }

            .envelope-container:hover .envelope {
                transition-delay: 150ms;
                -ms-transition-delay: 150ms;
                -moz-transition-delay: 150ms;
                -o-transition-delay: 150ms;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }

            .envelope-container .envelope .top {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 20;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                border-left: 100px solid transparent;
                border-right: 100px solid transparent;
                border-top: 100px solid #333;
                transform-origin: top;
                -ms-transform-origin: top;
                -moz-transform-origin: top;
                -o-transform-origin: top;
                -webkit-transform-origin: top;
                transition: transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, height 2s 0ms, top 2s 0ms;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, height 2s 0ms, top 2s 0ms;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, height 2s 0ms, top 2s 0ms;
                -o-transition: -o-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, height 2s 0ms, top 2s 0ms;
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, height 2s 0ms, top 2s 0ms;
            }

            .envelope-container:hover .envelope .top {
                transition: transform 2s 0ms, height 2s 150ms, top 2s 150ms;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s 0ms, height 2s 150ms, top 2s 150ms;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s 0ms, height 2s 150ms, top 2s 150ms;
                -o-transition: -o-transform 2s 0ms, height 2s 150ms, top 2s 150ms;
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s 0ms, height 2s 150ms, top 2s 150ms;
                height: 100px;
                top: 0px;
                transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
            }


            .envelope-container .envelope .right {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 20;
                top: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                border-right: 100px solid #333;
                border-top: 100px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
                 transform-origin: right;
                -ms-transform-origin: right;
                -moz-transform-origin: right;
                -o-transform-origin: right;
                -webkit-transform-origin: right;
                transition: transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, width 2s 0ms, right 2s 0ms;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, width 2s 0ms, right 2s 0ms;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, width 2s 0ms, right 2s 0ms;
                -o-transition: -o-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, width 2s 0ms, right 2s 0ms;
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, width 2s 0ms, right 2s 0ms;
            }

            .envelope-container:hover .envelope .right {
                transition: transform 2s 0ms, width 2s 150ms, right 2s 150ms;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s 0ms, width 2s 150ms, right 2s 150ms;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s 0ms, width 2s 150ms, right 2s 150ms;
                -o-transition: -o-transform 2s 0ms, width 2s 150ms, right 2s 150ms;
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s 0ms, width 2s 150ms, right 2s 150ms;
                width: 100px;
                right: 0px;
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
                -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
                -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            }

            .envelope-container .envelope .left {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 20;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                border-left: 100px solid #333;
                border-top: 100px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
                transform-origin: left;
                -ms-transform-origin: left;
                -moz-transform-origin: left;
                -o-transform-origin: left;
                -webkit-transform-origin: left;
                transition: transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, width 2s 0ms, left 2s 0ms;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, width 2s 0ms, left 2s 0ms;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, width 2s 0ms, left 2s 0ms;
                -o-transition: -o-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, width 2s 0ms, left 2s 0ms;
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, width 2s 0ms, left 2s 0ms;
            }

            .envelope-container:hover .envelope .left {
                transition: transform 2s 0ms, width 2s 150ms, left 2s 150ms;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s 0ms, width 2s 150ms, left 2s 150ms;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s 0ms, width 2s 150ms, left 2s 150ms;
                -o-transition: -o-transform 2s 0ms, width 2s 150ms, left 2s 150ms;
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s 0ms, width 2s 150ms, left 2s 150ms;
                width: 100px;
                left: 0px;
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
                -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
                -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            }

            .envelope-container .envelope .bottom {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 20;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                border-left: 100px solid transparent;
                border-right: 100px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 100px solid #333;
                 transform-origin: bottom;
                -ms-transform-origin: bottom;
                -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
                -o-transform-origin: bottom;
                -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
                transition: transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, height 2s 0ms, bottom 2s 0ms;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, height 2s 0ms, bottom 2s 0ms;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, height 2s 0ms, bottom 2s 0ms;
                -o-transition: -o-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, height 2s 0ms, bottom 2s 0ms;
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s 150ms, z-index 0ms 150ms, height 2s 0ms, bottom 2s 0ms;
            }

            .envelope-container:hover .envelope .bottom {
                transition: transform 2s 0ms, height 2s 150ms, left 2s 150ms;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s 0ms, height 2s 150ms, left 2s 150ms;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s 0ms, height 2s 150ms, left 2s 150ms;
                -o-transition: -o-transform 2s 0ms, height 2s 150ms, left 2s 150ms;
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s 0ms, height 2s 150ms, left 2s 150ms;
                height: 100px;
                bottom: 0px;
                transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
            }

            .envelope-container:hover .envelope .envelope-inner {
                background: #333;
            }

            .envelope-container .envelope .envelope-inner {
                position: absolute;
                height: 176px;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 176px;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                background: #fff;
                z-index: 10;
                border:2px solid black;
                transition: all 2s 0ms;
                -ms-transition: all 2s 0ms;
                -moz-transition: all 2s 0ms;
                -o-transition: all 2s 0ms;
                -webkit-transition: all 2s 0ms;
                
            }

            .envelope-container .envelope .envelope-inner p {
                margin: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-right: -50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                color:#fff;
                padding:10px;
            }
```

```html
<div id="envelope-bg">
    <div class="envelope-container">
        <div class="envelope">
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="envelope-inner">
                <p>This is a test message. This is a test message. This is a test message</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i've been trying it out and I haven't found a way to do exactly what I wanted. I was hoping to be able to do something like this: http://kovejadesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/010.gif;
but with this image:
http://www.wagsoft.com/David/img/icon.png;
and somehow unfolding and revealing some text.

Comment: I have updated the answer with another code snippet. Please check it out and see if you can use this as example to achieve what you want. Its pure css solution/plugin i built some time ago.